# Image Prediction Issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library

I made a model using CNN to predict if the given X-ray is of Covid patient or not.

**The issue i am facing**

1. There are some image which works fine while some throws error I can't put my finger on what's the problem is

Here is the error

```
ValueError: in user code:

/home/khushwant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1478 predict_function *
return step_function(self, iterator)
/home/khushwant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1468 step_function **
outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/home/khushwant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/home/khushwant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/home/khushwant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/home/khushwant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1461 run_step **
outputs = model.predict_step(data)
/home/khushwant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1434 predict_step
return self(x, training=False)
/home/khushwant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:998 __call__
input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
/home/khushwant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:255 assert_input_compatibility
raise ValueError(

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 64, 64, 1)
```

**How can you recreate an Issue?**

1. Clone the Repo [Repo link](https://github.com/WOLFIEEEE/Covid_Xray-model)
2. go to the folder and install requirement.txt
3. run cdclass.py
4. try uploading the images I put in a trial folder

You will see that the image in the corona folder works fine but as soon as I upload something from the normal folder it throws an error as I mentioned above.

**PS:-** I tried the prediction in the model ( in google colab when I was creating it ) the same image works just fine their but in deployment, it's throwing error) You will find a .ipynb file in Repo you are free to check it if you wish.

Comment: Can you add a link to the repo?

Comment: ohh sorry I forgot to do that

Comment: @RaJa sorry I just added link

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some of your images are not RGB images, but grayscale

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 64, 64, 1)
```

The error tells you that your model expects the input to have 3 color channels but the faulty images have only one (given by the 1 in the (None, 64, 64, 1)).

It is a similar problem as described here: [is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 256, 256, 3]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63867887/4141279)
But in this case, it seemed that the model was missing the correct input layer.

Comment: I tried fixing that using axis = -1 but then the model start predicting wrong Is there any turnaround become while creating and predicting in Google Colab it worked just fine

Comment: I think you you should check the input images first. The model was set up correctly. But sometimes gray images are saved as RGB and sometimes as Gray (1-channel). Especially, when using images from different sources

Comment: I don't think the Image is creating an issue here I think The library Pillow is creating the issue. I tried to deploy this model in another way ( where Instead of reading the image in byte format ) I was giving the path of stored Image and at that time It was working perfectly fine, I can share that code if you want .

Comment: @RaJa is correct here you are passing in images with `1 channel` when it expects `3 channels`. Using `axis = -1` will not change anything, the error means that the last index is supposed to be `3` not `1`.